# How to merge 2D rectangles into larger polygons [Java]

Tags: java, merge, polygon, shapes

I have a 2D polygon that only has lines that are perfectly horizontal or perfectly verticle. There are 2 other posts relating to this. However, one is merging multiple rectangles at once into a polygon, and the other is written in javascript.

I would like to take a rectangle of any size and add it to an existing 2D Polygon. Some examples are below.

[image: Before and After of rect merging into polygon]

In the diagram, each box represents 1 pixel. The navy boxes are the points that data exists for and the red and green boxes show how these points are connected. The points of both the red polygon and the green rectangle are held in a linked list (the order of points is what determines what point connects to what). Red and Green boxes don't exist in memory, they're used here only to show connections.

A point is defined as having an x and y coordinate.

How would I go about merging the green rectangle into the red polygon?
I really appreciate any help given thanks!

Edit: Here is some code that draws these shapes:

```
public class Core
{
    private static Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
    private static Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
    
    
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new Core();
    }
    
    public Core()
    {
        polygon = new Polygon(new int[] {0,12,12,24,24,32,32,12,12,5,5,0},new int[] {0,0,4,4,-3,-3,13,13,15,15,8,8},12);
        rect = new Rectangle(18,14,7,6);
        
        Draw2D drawing = new Draw2D();
        drawing.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public class Draw2D extends JFrame
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -1033542824627245527L;
 
        public Draw2D()
        {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(new DrawPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            pack();
        }
    }
    
    class DrawPane extends JComponent
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5457330297413941626L;
 
        public DrawPane() {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280,720));
        }
 
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setBackground(Color.black);
            g2.clearRect(0,0,1280,720);
            g2.translate(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
            g2.setColor(Color.white);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(0.001f));
            
            g2.draw(polygon);
            g2.draw(rect);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit 2:

A partial solution that I have is to inflate the rectangle by pushing each side out by 1 pixel/box, then checking if the entire side is inside one of the red polygon lines. By inside I mean collinear. A green rectangle side is sitting inside one of the red polygon sides.
If it does sit inside then leave the points there, if not move them back to where they originally were. Repeat this clockwise until all 4 sides have ha their points moved or not. Duplicate point objects that reference the same point as a point object that already exists will be deleted so that only 1 point object references 1 point.

[image]

This is only part of a solution as this method doesn't work when a rectangle is added on the edge of a polygon (shown in the first image, 2nd and 3rd examples from the top down).

Comment: Do you have any code for us to draw these shapes?

Comment: @akuzminykh Yes, I have some code here. 1 block = pixel. https://pastebin.com/qd9B76k7

Comment: Please post the code in your question. One thing you could try is to follow the red path counter-clock wise. Then you always try to go to the right relative to the movement direction. If there is no block on the right, you try to go to the front. If there is no block in front of you, then you go to the left. At some point you will switch from the red path to the green path automatically and back again.

Comment: @akuzminykh Yes, I did think about doing this initially. However, it would be too computationally expensive to do on larger/more complex polygons which is my end goal. I've updated the post to explain that the red and green boxes are not actually there and just show the point connections. I might be willing to check the rectangle pixel/box by pixel/box because I wouldn't allow it to be larger than a certain amount. But the polygon can be as big as it wants. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your problem by separating it in different parts. So the issue is based on lines.

**Horizontal case**

```
1.
   R1------R2

     xxxxxx (overlaps)

G1------------G2

2.
R1----------R2

     xxxxxxx (overlaps)

   G1------------G2

3.
R1---------------R2

     no overlapping

                      G1-----G2

...
```

**distance**: abs(R_y1 - G_y1)

**range of overlap**: x1 = max(R_x1,G_x1), x2 = min(R_x2,G_x2),

```
if (distance <= 1 && x1-x2 > 0) {
    // both lines are neighbours and has a valid overlapping range
}
```

**Vertical case**

Analogous to horizontal

As your boxes are stored in linked lists, you iterate both boxes and calculate distance and range of overlap.

```
List<Line> greenBox; // {Line((28,30),(60,30)) , Line((60,30),(60,50)), ...
List<Line> redBox;   // ...
for (Line r : redBox) {
    for (Line g : greenBox) {
        if (distance(r,g) <= 1 && rangeOfOverlap(r,g) > 0) {
            // both lines matches and can be merged over the range of overlaps
            merge(r,g);
        }
    }
}
```

This is just an example to inspire you. You'll need to check if the picked green and red line are both horizontal or both vertical.

The complexity of the algorhythm would be around at m^n (without merging) where n is the number of green lines and m is the number of red lines.

lol